# I have a PostgreSQL problem

Tags: command-line

How can I edit `update-rc.d` and add postgresql to whitelist and comment in blacklist

```
nano /usr/sbin/update-rc.d

Blacklist
# postgresql disabled (comment)

#Whitelis
postgresql enabled (add)
```

---

and how to grand permisson of postgresql

```
usermod -a -G aid_inet postgres
```

## Update

Output from commands

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up postgresql-9.4 (9.4.6-0+deb8u1) ...
[....] Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server: main[....]
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2016-03-15 09:24:51 UTC [15301-1] FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented
2016-03-15 09:24:51 UTC [15301-2] DETAI[FAILiled system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600). ... failed!
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.4 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
postgresql-9.4

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What error your get? Have you tried `sudo....` with your commands?

Comment: Yeah I will post the output

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up postgresql-9.4 (9.4.6-0+deb8u1) ...
[....] Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server: main[....] The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: 2016-03-15 09:24:51 UTC [15301-1] FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented 2016-03-15 09:24:51 UTC [15301-2] DETAI[FAILiled system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=40, 03600). ... failed!
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-9.4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.4

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)